# Why did Warren need to invent communication lacrimas?

Tags: fairy-tail

When members of fairy tail were traveling to defend magic council members they were communicating through lacrimas to the guild, and during the Phantom Lord arc Mira used a lacrima to contact Laxus, so why did they need to "invent" what were basically cell phones when they already had lacrimas to communicate over long distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason could be that the usual [Lacrima](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Lacrima) crystal, which is shaped like a crystal ball, looks a bit bulky. [image]

**Why did they need to "invent" what were basically cell phones when they already had lacrimas to communicate over long distances?** The Miniature Communication Lacrima invented by Warren which, as you pointed out, is shaped like cell phones are much smaller in size but has the same functionality. **This makes it easier to carry around.**